# SignalR 2.3 cannot read property client

Tags: javascript, c#, html, signalr

Good day,

Unfortunately, I can not get SignalR to work for a private 1 on 1 chat.

Here the following things that I have done:

References that are situated in the head tag of my layout page in the right order:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.js"></script>
```

Even added both bellow to check if either worked but no luck.

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:50581/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Have an Owin startup class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var config = new HubConfiguration();

            config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            config.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;

            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);
        }
    }
}
```

Have my chatHub class with my methods inside:

```
[HubName("chatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
    }
```

I have a javascript file named chatboxManager with the following inside:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var ChatHub = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');
```

Using the above I get a connection to the chatHub

[image]

but it does not recognise the .client the bellow:

```
// On New User Connected
debugger;
ChatHub.client.onNewUserConnected = function (id, name, userid) {
    AddUser(ChatHub, id, name, userid);
}
```

[image]

If I use this at the beginning of the js file nothing works:

```
var ChatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
```

Is there something else that I could be missing?

I have de-installed the packages and re-installed them.

Any advice would greatly be appreciated to get this running.

Kind regards and thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this might be the solution but give it a try

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://yourIpHere:yourPortNr/signalr");
var chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("chatHub");
```

Comment: Hi, @KakaMir I will try it once I have the solution up and running again. Thank you for your advice.